# Get All Credit Cards of a Customer in Braintree

Tags: php, braintree

With

```
$result = Braintree_Customer::find($id);
```

it's possible to fetch all data from a customer by providing an additional attribute. But if I want to fetch bulked data like all creditCards types it's not possible as I can't iterate through the creditCards attribute with a foreach or a for loop. Does this attribute contain a length or size value that I could use?

What here is the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible approach by simply checking for the last attribute of an object to be null.

```
public function getCustomerPaymentMethods($id)
{
    try {
        $i = 0;
        $result = Braintree_Customer::find($id);
        while($result->creditCards[$i]->token !== null) {
            $card[$i] = new stdClass();
            $card[$i]->token = $result->creditCards[$i]->token;
            $card[$i]->type = $result->creditCards[$i]->cardType;
            $card[$i]->default = $result->creditCards[$i]->default;
            $card[$i]->expired = $result->creditCards[$i]->expired;
            $card[$i]->last4 = $result->creditCards[$i]->last4;
            $i++;
        }
        return $card;
    } catch(Braintree_Exception_NotFound $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```